# Why SignalR change function hitting many many times?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, signalr, sqldependency

I try to develop an asp.net mvc application and also trying to use signalr. The problem is that i have two tables that control user notificitaions in project. I have a Notification table and also NotificationUser table which is many to many table of notification and user tables. I am trying achive that if a user create a notification to another user in system I try to show a pop-up that confirm user with a simple message like 'Hey!New notification received'. The problem is javascript change function of signalr hitting so many times.All step i used in signalR listed below

the stored procedure

```
    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetNotifications]

    @userid int
    AS
    BEGIN
    select n.Ntf_Title,Ntf_Description,n.Ntf_Date from dbo.SysNotifications n INNER JOIN dbo.SysNotificationUser u on  n.Ntf_ID =u.NtU_NtfID where    NtU_UserID=@userid AND NtU_IsRead=0
    END
```

The Hub

```
 [HubName("signalRHub")]
 public class NtfHub : Hub
 {
    [HubMethodName("notifyChanges")]
    public static void NotifyChanges()
    {
        var context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<NtfHub>();
        context.Clients.All.notifyChanges();
    }


}
```

The StartUp Class

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.MapSignalR();

    }
}
```

The Partial View

```
 [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult GetNtf()
    {

        //NtfRepo rp = new NtfRepo(this.HttpContext);
        string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conn"].ConnectionString;
        int userid =id;
        using (SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand sqlcom = new SqlCommand("[GetNotifications]", sqlcon))
            {
                sqlcon.Open();
                sqlcom.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                sqlcom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userid", userid);
                sqlcom.Notification = null;
                SqlDependency dependancy = new SqlDependency(sqlcom);
                dependancy.OnChange += dependancy_OnChange;
                var reader = sqlcom.ExecuteReader();
                var ntf= reader.Cast<IDataRecord>()
                   .Select(e => new PopulateNtfBar()
                   {
                       Title = e.GetString(0),
                       Description = e.GetString(1),
                       TimeDiff = FindDifferenceTime(e.GetDateTime(2))
                   }).ToList();
                return PartialView("~/Views/Shared/CheckNotification.cshtml", ntf);
            }
        }
    }
```

At Last,The Script

```
  $(function () {
        var notification = $.connection.signalRHub;

        // Create a function that the hub can call to broadcast messages.
        notification.client.notifyChanges = function () {
            getData();
            toastr.warning("Hey,You have Ntf");
        };

        // Start the connection.
        $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
            getData();
        }).fail(function (e) {
        });
    });


    function getData() {
        var tbl = $("#header_notification_bar")
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("GetNtf","Home")',
            contentType: 'application/html ; charset:utf-8',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'html'
        }).success(function (result) {
            tbl.empty().append(result);

        }).error(function () {

        });


    }
```

notification.client.notifyChanges hitting so many times if a user create a notification.Where is the problem? Any idea? i cannot optimize it

EDIT 1 
I am calling NtfHub.NotifyChanges in controller.

```
  void dependancy_OnChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Type == SqlNotificationType.Change)
        {
            NtfHub.NotifyChanges();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where are you calling `NtfHub.NotifyChanges()`? It is probably in that code that the server method is being called multiple times, either from JavaScript or C# calling it directly. Can you [edit] to add that code in?

Comment: @Rhumborl i edited the code

Comment: @Rhumborl its hitting like while(true) now

Comment: Could GetNtf() be being called more than once for the same user? - if so multiple change notifications will be received.  You may need to keep track of currently registered dependencies to avoid this.  Also, presumably you should be looking up the SignalR client relating to the changed user rather than firing the event to all clients?

Comment: I may be wrong but as @BenJackson suggests, I suspect it is because you are attaching `dependancy_OnChange()` each time `GetNtf()` is called.You need to do it once per user or just once.

Comment: Also make sure you reset IIS / IIS Express, as the web process is not necessarily restarted when you start debugging - thus you might have a lot of historic registered notification dependencies hanging around that are causing confusion.

Comment: @Rhumborl can you please explain in detail how to attach getntf only once ?

Comment: Using SqlDependency seems to be wrong for this kind of problem. [See notes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldependency(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @AlekseyL. any suggestion using another ?

Comment: Just send notification to specific user when the message is being sent

Comment: @mayk have you found any solution or did you face cakcuk problem

Comment: @ConvertToInt32 i have found no solution but most probobly there is a cakcuk problem my son.

Answer (score 0):

Although I think that SqlDependency is wrong approach for this feature, you could try to solve this specific problem this way:
Add parameter "subscribeToNotifications" to your controller action

```
public ActionResult GetNtf(bool subscribeToNotifications)
```

Create SqlDependency only if it is True.
Then subscribe to notifications **only** on hub started (this will prevent creation of multiple SqlDependencies for same user):

```
$(function () {
    var notification = $.connection.signalRHub;

    // Create a function that the hub can call to broadcast messages.
    notification.client.notifyChanges = function () {
        getData(false);
        toastr.warning("Hey,You have Ntf");
    };

    // Start the connection.
    $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
        getData(true);
    }).fail(function (e) {
    });
});


function getData(subscribeToNotifications) {
    var tbl = $("#header_notification_bar")
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("GetNtf","Home")' + '?subscribeToNotifications=' + subscribeToNotifications,
        contentType: 'application/html ; charset:utf-8',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'html'
    }).success(function (result) {
        tbl.empty().append(result);

    }).error(function () {

    });
}
```

But be aware that every page refresh will still create new listener without managing subscriptions on server side.

**Option 2** is to create single SqlDependency (on server app start) omitting userId parameter - anyway you are sending notification to **all** users no matter which one got the message.

**Option 3** - the real solution is get rid of SqlDependency at all and send notification **only** to specific user (recipient of the message)

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that you are not unsubscribing from the dependancy_OnChange event, a sqldependency trigger is a one shot execution, so you have to subscribe to the new one every time it fires, what you are not doing is unsubscribing from the previous event handler, so when you subscribe to the new one, you now have multiple handlers for the same trigger.

```
private void dependency_OnChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
{   
    SqlDependency dependency = sender as SqlDependency;
    if (dependency != null) dependency.OnChange -= dependency_OnChange;
    //Recall your SQLDependency setup method here.
    SetupDependency();
}
```

Comment: thank you for your response but it is not hitting the script function notification.client.notifyChanges = function () {
            getData();
            toastr.warning("Hey,You have Ntf");
        }; now

Comment: Try taking the context out you shouldn't need it, the hub should already have it. Clients.All.notifyChanges();